# Accessing data from dynamic control in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamic-data

On `Grid_RowDataBound` I have added a table in the 8th cell of the current row. This table is like:

```
<table rules="all" border="0" style="width:100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input name="studentgrd$ctl03$ID2VAL4" type="text" value="6" maxlength="2" id="studentgrd_ctl03_ID2VAL4" style="width:20px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

On save button click, I tried to get the data using:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)studentgrd.FindControl("ID2VAL4");
TextBox tb = (TextBox)studentgrd.Rows[i].Cells[8].FindControl("ID2VAL4");//When looping through all rows
```

But the textboxes were null. So are the dynamic controls lost on postback? If yes, then how to retain it? If it is not, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Yes dynamic controls value lost on postback. To get value add hidden field then put value of textbox in hidden field using javascript on lostfocus event of textbox.

Comment: there will dynamic number of text box in that cell how to decide on number of hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a GridviewRow like this in your button click method:

```
GridViewRow gridViewRow = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);
```

When assigning value you should change it to:

```
TextBox tb = ((TextBox)gridViewRow .FindControl("ID2VAL4"));
```

where `gridViewRow` is a `GridViewRow` that is used not the `GridView` itself.

Comment: But Grid_RowDataBound will not called on postback and button is not in grid also.I disabled grid databind on postback and when all statements are finished in button_Click there is line last line studentgrd.DataBind(); to reflect the changes.

Comment: I changed the answer. The code above will only be in the event method and not in the DataRowBound.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.secure_studentgrade_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'. :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem: if it is a dynamically-generated control, and bounded to data source that is loaded for the first time, then on post back you have to again generate the same control and bind it, and then try to access them.

Even if the dynamic control is created and bound to a datasource just no,w it will have the changed value given by user (which surprises me, I think because of the view state of the dynamic control. Correct me if am wrong).